# Hyperlink in \todo[inline]

Tags: hyperref, todonotes

Do anyone have an idea why I have this two errors when using a `\hyperlink{}{}` in `\todo[inline]` ??

> 1- Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
>
> 2- Paragraph ended befor \reserved@a was complete.

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

The mandatory argument of macro `\todo` from package `todonotes` is written to the auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.tdo` for the list of todos), thus it is a "moving argument", where fragile macros break. `\hyperlink` can be protected with `\protect`:

```
\todo[inline]{\protect{hyperlink}{...}{...}}
```